# ARM template link to refactor template values

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

**Summary**: We have Below mentioned release pipelines
1. Release1 -This pipeline will create resources like Application insights, App service plan, Key vault. (ARM files -azuredeploy.json and azuredeployparameters.json)
2. Release2 Pipeline: This pipeline will create resources like App service/Function App using Release1 components like Application insights, App service plan, Key vault. (ARM files -azuredeploy.json and azuredeployparameters.json)

We have multiple micro services In Release2 pipelines, 
Environments like Dev, QA, Test . 
Each environment has separate resource group.

azuredeployparameters.json all values are same for all services except webapp name.

**Issue**:If we want change or update any value in all azuredeployparameters.json files in all Release2 pipeline services, We are updating manually.

**Kindly suggest the solution on below:**
Can we link all our release2 azuredeployparameters.json files to one centralized azuredeployparameters.json file. 
If we modify centralized azuredeployparameters.json file, it should update all azuredeployparameters.json files in all release 2 services.

Comment: create a script for that?

Comment: Can we use ARM Nested/linked templates? if yes  could you please suggest, how to create it

Comment: @muralid Do you use Azure DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxx)?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Yes, We use Azure Devops

Answer (score 0):

You can put your azuredeployparameters.json in your central/main repo. And if you use release pipelines for instance, you should create build for your central repo and publish azuredeployparameters.json as artifact. You can later use this artifacts in any release pipeline you want. So you can get it Release1 and Release2.

If you use build pipelines also to deploy, you can use multiple repos and get source code (in release 1) from your central repo and repo dedicated to this release. In the same way you have this file available.

If you want to customize file a bit in Relese pipeline you can tokenize you azuredeployparameters.json file and replace those tokens in release. [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) you have extension for this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have created nested ARM templates and kept on Github. Can we put  ARM templates on Azure git repo?. Could you please let me know the steps to use Nested ARM templates on Azure git repo.

Comment: @muralid Have you checked links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/deploy-nested-template-environments, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/add-template-to-azure-pipelines? Are they help you?